# regular expression differences in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following HTML that I wish to find the currently playing artist and song title my regular expression works in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it compiles in Java correctly yet it doesn't match anything

HTML snippet

```html
<div class="audio_playing_title">Currently Playing.
  <div class="audio_home_box">
     <div class="audio_playing_stats">
        <div class="audio_playing">
           <div class="audio_dj_title">PRESENTER:
                AutoDJ - The Slogan
           </div>
          <div class="audio_track_title">SONG TITLE:
               The Artist Name - Song Name
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The Java code

```java
String data = getWebsiteData(url);
data = data.replace("\\t", "");

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"audio_track_title\">SONG TITLE:\r(.+)\r</div>");

Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(data);

if (matcher.matches())
{
    data = matcher.group(1);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("No match");
}
return data;
```

Comment: I would say stop using RegEx for HTML parsing. Instead, use a dedicated library for this like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: why regex..use parser..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that [`Matcher#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) only returns true if the whole sequence matches your regex.

You need [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29), which will look for matching subsequences.

I also think you would be better off using the [`Pattern#DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag to let your `.` match line breaks too instead of trying to match them yourself, since the line break standard differs between systems:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"audio_track_title\">SONG TITLE:\r(.+)\r</div>", Pattern.DOTALL);
```